# Residue Theorem for Improper Integral

Tags: improper-integrals, complex-integration

$$\int^\infty_0 log(1+x^2)\frac{dx}{x^{1+\alpha}}(0<\alpha<2)$$

How to do with the log and it says try integration by parts.

Comment: So what happened when you tried integration by parts?

Comment: two log function?

Comment: the result should be $$\frac{\pi  \csc \left(\frac{\pi  \alpha }{2}\right)}{\alpha }$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Can you give the step of solution?

Comment: Which function did you integrate?

Comment: The title says residue theorem; the body says integration by parts... which solution do you prefer?

Comment: It should be solved by the residue theorem but the hint says considering integration by parts.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't fear following the book hint.

$$ I=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\log(1+x^2)\frac{dx}{x^{1+\alpha}} \stackrel{\text{IBP}}{=} \frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\cdot \frac{dx}{x^\alpha} $$
and by setting $\frac{1}{1+x^2}=u$ the last integral turns into a value for a [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function):

$$ I = \frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{0}^{1} u^{\frac{\alpha}{2}-1}(1-u)^{-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\,du = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\,\Gamma\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}{\alpha}=\frac{\pi}{\alpha \sin\frac{\pi\alpha}{2}} $$
where the last equality follows from the reflection formula for the $\Gamma$ function.
The same result can be achieved by computing $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{1-\alpha}}{1+x^2}\,dx $$
through suitable contours in the complex plane.

Comment: Can you explain how to achieve by the complex plane contours using residue teorem?

Comment: @stedmoaoa: that has been asked on MSE multiple times. A simple search should do the job nicely, but it is worth to try to solve it on your own first.

Comment: I don't understand whether the last integration is a equal one.